# System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItem has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, listviewitem

I am new to C#. I am simply trying to create a `ListViewItem` object. However no matter what I try, Visual Studio keeps on complaining the constructor argument is invalid.

I checked the MSDN website for `ListViewItem's API` on its constructor. It allows no argument and string arrays. But no matter what I place inside the braces for the constructor arguments, I still receive the same error message from Visual Studio.

```
public partial class testForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] str= { "a", "b", "c" };
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(str);  //Error from here
    }
}
```

**Error:** System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItem has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right ListViewItem? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The one you want to look for is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Steen How do I place the correct llistViewItem into the form? I am currently dragging the listViewItem component from the toolbox. I want to use the listViewItem which allows me to use string array in the constructor.

Comment: @CoderofCode But how am I allowed to add ListItem objects into a ListView ? It seems that I am not allowed to do that...

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I didnt looked at it correctly.